# How could I send the token returned from a post request in a get request in Angular

Tags: angular, post, get, token

I need to send a token that I receive in a post request. I have to send the token in a get request, what I am doing is to save the token returned by the post request in one, notice that in `GetToken` I send it to show by console and if it is shown, that is, the assignment if it is doing, but when I try to print it from `ObternerInmueble()` it prints empty, I do not know why?

Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {
  cabecera = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ""
  }

  parametros = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 1,
    'client_secret': 'clientSecret'
  }

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  obtenerToken(){
    return this.http.post<any>('URL',this.parametros).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.cabecera.Authorization=result.token_type+" "+result.access_token;
        console.log(this.cabecera.Authorization);  //here I can see that the value is being allocated
        this.obtenerInmuebles().subscribe();

      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  obtenerInmuebles() {
    console.log("Authorization-----------_>"+this.cabecera.Authorization);
    return this.http.get<any>('URL',{ headers: new HttpHeaders(this.cabecera) 
    });
  }

  mostrarCabecera(){
    console.log("CABECERA::::::::"+this.cabecera.Authorization);
  }
}
```

This is where he called the methods:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  i: number=0;

  url: string = "http://crm.seaconfiable.com/upload/";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken();
    this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log("INMUEBLES",result.data);
      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the image of the browser console where you can see that the Authorization header is being sent empty (blank):

[image: consola del navegador]

Comment: Try to set return type as observable in obtenerInmuebles() method then subscribe it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following lines -

```
this.hostlistService.obtenerToken();
this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles().subscribe
```

this.hostlistService.obtenerToken() method issue a HTTP call when you subscribe, while the response is awaited [because of the async nature of JS], the other line got executed this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles().subscribe.

You must wait for the response from this.hostlistService.obtenerToken() observable. To do that, you should use observable chaining by using pipe function (see "Piping" topic at https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) and chaining various operators (as per your need).

You can do the following -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {

    cabecera = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': ""
    }

    parametros = {
      'grant_type':'client_credentials',
      'client_id': 1,
      'client_secret': 'clientSecret'
    }


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }


  obtenerToken(){
    return this.http.post<any>('URL',this.parametros);    
  }


  obtenerInmuebles(resultToken){
    console.log("Authorization-----------_>"+this.cabecera.Authorization);
    this.cabecera.Authorization=resultToken.token_type+" "+resultToken.access_token;
    return this.http.get<any>('URL',{ headers: new HttpHeaders(this.cabecera) });
  }

  mostrarCabecera(){
    console.log("CABECERA::::::::"+this.cabecera.Authorization);
  }

}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  i: number=0;

  url: string = "http://crm.seaconfiable.com/upload/";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(resultToken => this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken))
        )
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log("INMUEBLES",result.data);
          },error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );    
  }
}
```

I have modified your code only. Although there could be a better way to do the same. Hope this helps.

In the above code, I have used pipe function on this.hostlistService.obtenerToken() and apply mergeMap operator which will ensure to call this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken)) observable once the response of this.hostlistService.obtenerToken() has been received and this is what we want.

I would highly recommend checking the following websites to know more about rxjs and various operators -

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview
https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Also, you can avoid the explicit call to subscribe() by using async pipe. See the following - https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

**EDIT 2 [This edit is done to show how to save token in the localStorage [as requested by the user]** -

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(resultToken => {
            //do whatever you want to do with the token
            //i.e. Save the token in the localstorage like this - 
            localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken);
            return this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken);
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log("INMUEBLES",result.data);
          },error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );    
  }
```

Comment: hello @ user2216584 I worked your code, but starting with Angula recently, could you explain a little what you did? especially about "pipe" and "mergeMap"?

Comment: friend how could I do to save the resultToken in the localstorage? I'm trying this:      this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(resultToken => this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken), localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken))
        )  , friend how could I do to save the resultToken in the localstorage? I'm trying this: this.hostlistService.getToken ()
         .pipe (
           mergeMap (resultToken => this.hostlistService.getInput (resultToken), localStorage.setItem ("token", resultToken))
         )   but it does not work.

Comment: @JulianProg To save the token you simply call `localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken)` before returning the new observable. See my "EDIT 2" in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, mark your answer as a solution. Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm starting with Angular and even though I read the documentation and look for examples, it's hard for me to understand. Right now I am trying to use binding between components to pass the real property to and print it from the template of another component and I have many doubts. Would you be so kind if it is not too much trouble, to pass me a social network where I can contact you?

Comment: @JulianProg You are very welcome! It is fine to ask as many questions as you want. That's what this community for..:) For anyone, any new thing has a learning curve and having questions is a right way to explore the new thing..:) So keep asking..:) Also all community members also learn something new whenever other community members ask the questions..:) I would love to help you anytime. Just that I do not want to share my social platform details on a public platform. If you can suggest some way to contact you, I will contact you for sure.

Comment: You are very kind friend. my email is julian21931500@gmail.com, I would be very happy if you could communicate with me.